# Apply a transparent background color to a particular table[row][col]

Tags: php, html, css, html-table

I want the background color of a particular cell of a `table` to be light yellow (i.e. transparent yellow), for which i used the attribute `'rgba'`.

I even removed the background for the whole division so that transparency of the color is maintained. But it just shows black color as the background.

```html
<div id="top">
 <table height="60px" width="1030px">
 <tr> 
  <th bgcolor="rgba(222,215,11,0.3)"><u><a href="forum.php" class="class2">Forum</a></u></th>
  <th><u><a href="quest.php"class="class2">My Questions</a></u></th>
  <th><u><a href="answers.php"class="class2">My Answers</a></u></th>
 </tr>
 </table> 
</div>
```

Comment: added a full explanation below. i guess you haven't written in HTML in a long time, or you haven't used HTML 5 :) no worries , it's easy to get used to the 'new' features

Answer (score 1):

Use proper css style: background-color

```html
<div id="top">
<table height="60px" width="1030px">
<tr> 
<th style="background-color: rgba(222,215,11,0.3)"><u><a href="forum.php" class="class2">Forum</a></u></th>
<th><u><a href="quest.php"class="class2">My Questions</a></u></th>
<th><u><a href="answers.php"class="class2">My Answers</a></u></th>
</tr>
</table> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> `<body bgcolor="color_name|hex_number|rgb_number">`

***The  bgcolor attribute is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead.***

see here **[bgcolor](http://bgcolor)**

but instead you should use the `background-color`  property

> `background-color: color|transparent|initial|inherit;`

which can be written in CSS `th { background-color:rgba(222,215,11,0.3) }`

or Inline CSS `<th style="background-color:rgba(222,215,11,0.3)"></th>`

more info here **[background-color](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-color.asp)**

also i suggest you don't use `<u>` tag especially on `<a>` tags that are by default underlined.

> The  element was deprecated in HTML 4.01. (the  element was used to define underlined text).
>
> The  element is redefined in HTML5, to represent text that should be stylistically different from normal text, such as misspelled words or proper nouns in Chinese.

like in the case of `bgcolor`, i suggest you use CSS or inline CSS using `text-decoration:underline` instead of `<u>`

read more here **[HTML < u > Tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_u.asp)**

for your answer. see snippet below. Cheers ;)

```html
<div id="top">
<table height="60px" width="1030px">
<tr> 
<th style="background-color:rgba(222,215,11,0.3)"><a href="forum.php" class="class2">Forum</a></th>
<th><a href="quest.php"class="class2">My Questions</a></th>
<th><a href="answers.php"class="class2">My Answers</a></th>
</tr>
</table> 
</div>
```

Comment: glad i could help :) don't forget to rate my answer as accepted . so if someone else needs help in this matter to see the answer. thanks ! :D

Answer (score 0):

`BGColor` was deprecated in the W3C HTML 4.0 Specification. Also, `bgcolor` does not work with `rgba` values.

Use CSS style `background-color` instead of `bgcolor`.

```html
<div id="top">
<table height="60px" width="1030px">
<tr> 
<th style="background-color: rgba(222,215,11,0.3)"><u><a href="forum.php" class="class2">Forum</a></u></th>
<th><u><a href="quest.php"class="class2">My Questions</a></u></th>
<th><u><a href="answers.php"class="class2">My Answers</a></u></th>
</tr>
</table> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `style` instead of `bgcolor`

```html
<div id="top">
 <table height="60px" width="1030px">
  <tr> 
   <th style="background:rgba(222,215,11,0.3)"><u><a href="forum.php" class="class2">Forum</a></u></th>
   <th><u><a href="quest.php"class="class2">My Questions</a></u></th>
   <th><u><a href="answers.php"class="class2">My Answers</a></u></th>
  </tr>
 </table> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use # color coding.

Can you please try below.

```html
<div id="top">
 <table height="60px" width="1030px">
   <tr> 
    <th bgcolor="#FFFFE0"><u><a href="forum.php" class="class2">Forum</a></u></th>
    <th><u><a href="quest.php"class="class2">My Questions</a></u></th>
    <th><u><a href="answers.php"class="class2">My Answers</a></u></th>
   </tr>
  </table> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try inline css.

```
<div id="top">
    <table height="60px" width="1030px">
        <tr> 
            <th style="background-color: #ffff99 "><u><a href="forum.php" class="class2">Forum</a></u></th>
            <th><u><a href="quest.php"class="class2">My Questions</a></u></th>
            <th><u><a href="answers.php"class="class2">My Answers</a></u></th>
        </tr>
    </table> 
</div>
```